# Sending file to Container Instance (Docker) post-launch

Tags: git, azure, docker, jenkins, ssh

I'm using Jenkins with azure-container-agents-plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-container-agents-plugin) to launch a node as Docker instance on Azure.

I have a image based on https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jnlp-slave/ that is setup to launch based on a Jenkins job.

The purpose of the job is to take in a generic shell script and run the script on the Jenkins node. This is so that an 3rd party application could send the script to Jenkins as a "parameter" to the job so it could run different scripts based on different situations.

Part of a script could be performing a git pull, which requires credentials or SSH key.

This there a way to transfer the SSH key to the container instance after the launch but before the script is executed on the node?

Comment: Additionally, I know there's a way to copy files from the host to the docker instance using the "docker cp" command after the launch. However, how to do something similar from a Jenkins job context\perspective?

Comment: Didn't you try to mount your host machine' .ssh directory when you run your docker container?

Comment: @chamindaindika, the container is ran by the azure-container-agents-plugin. I'm not quite sure how to tell it to mount something. The container runs somewhere on the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin for Jenkins that I think it can solve your problem. It's Copy data to workspace ([Copy Data To Workspace - Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copy-data-to-workspace-plugin)).
This plugin is to copy data from master node to workspace directory in slave. This step will be done before Build steps is executed.